# Recharts Bar Size not calculated automatically when scale is point

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I am using recharts to display a composite chart.

```
const Chart = ({ responseAverage }) => {
  responseAverage = responseAverage.sort((a, b) => a.label - b.label);
  return (
    <ResponsiveContainer width={700} height={400}>
      <ComposedChart
        data={responseAverage}
      >
        <CartesianGrid horizontal={false} strokeDasharray="4 4" />
        <XAxis scale="point" dataKey="label" />
        <YAxis label={{ value: 'No.Of Employees', angle: -90, position: 'insideLeft' }} tick={false} height={20} />
        {/* <Tooltip cursor={false} content={<CustomTooltip teamData={teamData} />} /> */}
        <Bar dataKey="count" barSize={40} fill="#AAE5F9" />
        <Line connectNulls={true} strokeWidth={3} dot={false} type="monotone" dataKey="count" stroke="#3080ED" />
        {/* <LabelList dataKey="name" position="insideTop" /> */}
      </ComposedChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
  );
};
```

In this I am specifying the barSize. But it dosent work in all cases. I want the Bar size to calculate automatically based on the number of values

[image]

Is there any workaround for this problem ?

Any help would be really thankfull

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the gaps between the bars, you need to remove the `barSize` parameter from the `Bar` and add the `barCategoryGap={0}` parameter to the `ComposedChart` component.

```js
const Chart = ({ responseAverage }) => {
  responseAverage = responseAverage.sort((a, b) => a.label - b.label);
  return (
    <ResponsiveContainer width={700} height={400}>
      <ComposedChart
        barCategoryGap={0}
        data={responseAverage}
      >
        <CartesianGrid horizontal={false} strokeDasharray="4 4" />
        <XAxis scale="point" dataKey="label" />
        <YAxis label={{ value: 'No.Of Employees', angle: -90, position: 'insideLeft' }} tick={false} height={20} />
        {/* <Tooltip cursor={false} content={<CustomTooltip teamData={teamData} />} /> */}
        <Bar dataKey="count" fill="#AAE5F9" />
        <Line connectNulls={true} strokeWidth={3} dot={false} type="monotone" dataKey="count" stroke="#3080ED" />
        {/* <LabelList dataKey="name" position="insideTop" /> */}
      </ComposedChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
  );
};
```

If as a result, thin lines remain between the bars, then you can do this:

```js
<Bar dataKey="count" fill="#AAE5F9" stroke="#AAE5F9" strokeWidth={2} />
```